# AngularJS time input format of 24hours

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to use input time field but I need to have 24-hours format. And I don't need this to be browser specific.

Does anyone knows some alternative to this input tag?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the same input tag only just do some changes before storing the input in database.This won't be any browser  specific.

```
var time = $("#starttime").val();
var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
var AMPM = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
if(AMPM == "PM" && hours<12) hours = hours+12;
if(AMPM == "AM" && hours==12) hours = hours-12;
var sHours = hours.toString();
var sMinutes = minutes.toString();
if(hours<10) sHours = "0" + sHours;
if(minutes<10) sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;
alert(sHours + ":" + sMinutes);
```